# Package conflict detect in conda but not create the environment

Tags: python, conda

I use miniconda3 to create virtual environment in linux aarch64 architecture.
I wrote penvstack.yml file

```
name: ymlenv
channels:

  - conda-forge/label/gcc7
  - anaconda
  - conda-forge
  - r
  - defaults
 
dependencies:
  - tensorflow
  - fpdf
  - kneed
  - jsonschema
  - python-Levenshtein
  - librosa==0.9.2
  - matplotlib
  - numpy==1.22.4
  - pytz
  - pickleshare
  - pandas
  - rdp
  - seaborn==0.11.2
  - scikit-learn
  - scipy==1.9.0
  - watchdog==2.1.9
  - python
```

When I create the conda environment, I use the yaml file and create. But while creating, it said Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages. But in the end shows the following packages with version and it does not install the packages in conda.
May I know how can I solve this issue?

```
(base) : conda env create -f penvstack.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: -
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.                                                                                                                                                                                        failed                                                              |                                                                                                                                                                        /
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.                                                                                                                                                                                     failed                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       /

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versions

Package llvm-openmp conflicts for:
scikit-learn -> _openmp_mutex -> llvm-openmp[version='>=9.0.1']
scipy -> blas=[build=openblas] -> llvm-openmp[version='>=10.0.0|>=11.0.0|>=11.0.1|>=11.1.0|>=12.0.1|>=13.0.1|>=14.0.4|>=9.0.1|>=10.0.1']
numpy -> blas=[build=openblas] -> llvm-openmp[version='>=10.0.0|>=11.0.0|>=11.0.1|>=11.1.0|>=12.0.1|>=13.0.1|>=14.0.4|>=9.0.1|>=10.0.1']

Package pathlib2 conflicts for:
pickleshare -> pathlib2
jsonschema -> importlib_metadata -> pathlib2

Package numpy-base conflicts for:
seaborn -> numpy[version='>=1.9.3'] -> numpy-base[version='1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.22.3|1.23.1|1.23.1|1.23.1',build='py38h4a83355_0|py37h0361ad9_2|py38h0361ad9_2|py39h0361ad9_2|py38hdcdd103_4|py38h6383fca_0|py37hb31b9b9_1|py39h6ba5a95_0|py310h68f088d_0|py37h58d2a9e_0|py38h58d2a9e_0|py37h3af0daa_1|py38h3af0daa_1|py310he6496e5_1|py39h3af0daa_1|py37h3af0daa_2|py39h3af0daa_2|py38h4a83355_3|py37h4a83355_3|py310h5f09236_3|py310he6496e5_0|py39h3af0daa_0|py38h3af0daa_0|py39h4a83355_3|py310he6496e5_2|py38h3af0daa_2|py39h58d2a9e_0|py310h0d37565_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py37h53d150a_1|py38h53d150a_1|py39h53d150a_1|py38h53d150a_0|py37h53d150a_0|py39h53d150a_0|py39hb31b9b9_1|py38hb31b9b9_1|py39h6383fca_0|py37h6383fca_0|py37hdcdd103_4|py39hdcdd103_4|py310h5f09236_0|py39h4a83355_0']
numpy -> numpy-base[version='1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.22.3|1.23.1|1.23.1|1.23.1',build='py38h4a83355_0|py37h0361ad9_2|py38h0361ad9_2|py39h0361ad9_2|py38hdcdd103_4|py38h6383fca_0|py37hb31b9b9_1|py39h6ba5a95_0|py310h68f088d_0|py37h58d2a9e_0|py38h58d2a9e_0|py37h3af0daa_1|py38h3af0daa_1|py310he6496e5_1|py39h3af0daa_1|py37h3af0daa_2|py39h3af0daa_2|py38h4a83355_3|py37h4a83355_3|py310h5f09236_3|py310he6496e5_0|py39h3af0daa_0|py38h3af0daa_0|py39h4a83355_3|py310he6496e5_2|py38h3af0daa_2|py39h58d2a9e_0|py310h0d37565_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py37h53d150a_1|py38h53d150a_1|py39h53d150a_1|py38h53d150a_0|py37h53d150a_0|py39h53d150a_0|py39hb31b9b9_1|py38hb31b9b9_1|py39h6383fca_0|py37h6383fca_0|py37hdcdd103_4|py39hdcdd103_4|py310h5f09236_0|py39h4a83355_0']
pandas -> numpy[version='>=1.21.5,<2.0a0'] -> numpy-base[version='1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.22.3|1.23.1|1.23.1|1.23.1',build='py37h0361ad9_2|py38h0361ad9_2|py37hdcdd103_4|py37hb31b9b9_1|py39h53d150a_0|py38h53d150a_0|py37h53d150a_1|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h4a83355_0|py310h5f09236_0|py37h58d2a9e_0|py38h58d2a9e_0|py37h3af0daa_1|py38h3af0daa_1|py310he6496e5_1|py39h3af0daa_1|py37h3af0daa_2|py39h3af0daa_2|py38h4a83355_3|py37h4a83355_3|py310h5f09236_3|py310he6496e5_0|py39h3af0daa_0|py38h3af0daa_0|py39h4a83355_3|py310he6496e5_2|py38h3af0daa_2|py39h58d2a9e_0|py310h0d37565_0|py39h4a83355_0|py310h68f088d_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py38h53d150a_1|py39h53d150a_1|py37h53d150a_0|py39hb31b9b9_1|py38hb31b9b9_1|py39h6383fca_0|py37h6383fca_0|py38h6383fca_0|py39hdcdd103_4|py38hdcdd103_4|py39h0361ad9_2']
scipy -> numpy[version='>=1.21.5,<2.0a0'] -> numpy-base[version='1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.22.3|1.23.1|1.23.1|1.23.1',build='py37h0361ad9_2|py38h0361ad9_2|py37hdcdd103_4|py37hb31b9b9_1|py39h53d150a_0|py38h53d150a_0|py37h53d150a_1|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h4a83355_0|py310h5f09236_0|py37h58d2a9e_0|py38h58d2a9e_0|py37h3af0daa_1|py38h3af0daa_1|py310he6496e5_1|py39h3af0daa_1|py37h3af0daa_2|py39h3af0daa_2|py38h4a83355_3|py37h4a83355_3|py310h5f09236_3|py310he6496e5_0|py39h3af0daa_0|py38h3af0daa_0|py39h4a83355_3|py310he6496e5_2|py38h3af0daa_2|py39h58d2a9e_0|py310h0d37565_0|py39h4a83355_0|py310h68f088d_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py38h53d150a_1|py39h53d150a_1|py37h53d150a_0|py39hb31b9b9_1|py38hb31b9b9_1|py39h6383fca_0|py37h6383fca_0|py38h6383fca_0|py39hdcdd103_4|py38hdcdd103_4|py39h0361ad9_2']
kneed -> numpy -> numpy-base[version='1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.22.3|1.23.1|1.23.1|1.23.1',build='py38h4a83355_0|py37h0361ad9_2|py38h0361ad9_2|py39h0361ad9_2|py38hdcdd103_4|py38h6383fca_0|py37hb31b9b9_1|py39h6ba5a95_0|py310h68f088d_0|py37h58d2a9e_0|py38h58d2a9e_0|py37h3af0daa_1|py38h3af0daa_1|py310he6496e5_1|py39h3af0daa_1|py37h3af0daa_2|py39h3af0daa_2|py38h4a83355_3|py37h4a83355_3|py310h5f09236_3|py310he6496e5_0|py39h3af0daa_0|py38h3af0daa_0|py39h4a83355_3|py310he6496e5_2|py38h3af0daa_2|py39h58d2a9e_0|py310h0d37565_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py37h53d150a_1|py38h53d150a_1|py39h53d150a_1|py38h53d150a_0|py37h53d150a_0|py39h53d150a_0|py39hb31b9b9_1|py38hb31b9b9_1|py39h6383fca_0|py37h6383fca_0|py37hdcdd103_4|py39hdcdd103_4|py310h5f09236_0|py39h4a83355_0']
scikit-learn -> numpy[version='>=1.21.5,<2.0a0'] -> numpy-base[version='1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.22.3|1.23.1|1.23.1|1.23.1',build='py37h0361ad9_2|py38h0361ad9_2|py37hdcdd103_4|py37hb31b9b9_1|py39h53d150a_0|py38h53d150a_0|py37h53d150a_1|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h4a83355_0|py310h5f09236_0|py37h58d2a9e_0|py38h58d2a9e_0|py37h3af0daa_1|py38h3af0daa_1|py310he6496e5_1|py39h3af0daa_1|py37h3af0daa_2|py39h3af0daa_2|py38h4a83355_3|py37h4a83355_3|py310h5f09236_3|py310he6496e5_0|py39h3af0daa_0|py38h3af0daa_0|py39h4a83355_3|py310he6496e5_2|py38h3af0daa_2|py39h58d2a9e_0|py310h0d37565_0|py39h4a83355_0|py310h68f088d_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py38h53d150a_1|py39h53d150a_1|py37h53d150a_0|py39hb31b9b9_1|py38hb31b9b9_1|py39h6383fca_0|py37h6383fca_0|py38h6383fca_0|py39hdcdd103_4|py38hdcdd103_4|py39h0361ad9_2']
librosa -> numpy[version='>=1.8.0'] -> numpy-base[version='1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.22.3|1.23.1|1.23.1|1.23.1',build='py38h4a83355_0|py37h0361ad9_2|py38h0361ad9_2|py39h0361ad9_2|py38hdcdd103_4|py38h6383fca_0|py37hb31b9b9_1|py39h6ba5a95_0|py310h68f088d_0|py37h58d2a9e_0|py38h58d2a9e_0|py37h3af0daa_1|py38h3af0daa_1|py310he6496e5_1|py39h3af0daa_1|py37h3af0daa_2|py39h3af0daa_2|py38h4a83355_3|py37h4a83355_3|py310h5f09236_3|py310he6496e5_0|py39h3af0daa_0|py38h3af0daa_0|py39h4a83355_3|py310he6496e5_2|py38h3af0daa_2|py39h58d2a9e_0|py310h0d37565_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py37h53d150a_1|py38h53d150a_1|py39h53d150a_1|py38h53d150a_0|py37h53d150a_0|py39h53d150a_0|py39hb31b9b9_1|py38hb31b9b9_1|py39h6383fca_0|py37h6383fca_0|py37hdcdd103_4|py39hdcdd103_4|py310h5f09236_0|py39h4a83355_0']
rdp -> numpy -> numpy-base[version='1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.16.6|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.19.2|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.1|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.2|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.20.3|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.2|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.21.5|1.22.3|1.23.1|1.23.1|1.23.1',build='py38h4a83355_0|py37h0361ad9_2|py38h0361ad9_2|py39h0361ad9_2|py38hdcdd103_4|py38h6383fca_0|py37hb31b9b9_1|py39h6ba5a95_0|py310h68f088d_0|py37h58d2a9e_0|py38h58d2a9e_0|py37h3af0daa_1|py38h3af0daa_1|py310he6496e5_1|py39h3af0daa_1|py37h3af0daa_2|py39h3af0daa_2|py38h4a83355_3|py37h4a83355_3|py310h5f09236_3|py310he6496e5_0|py39h3af0daa_0|py38h3af0daa_0|py39h4a83355_3|py310he6496e5_2|py38h3af0daa_2|py39h58d2a9e_0|py310h0d37565_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py39h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py37h6ba5a95_0|py38h6ba5a95_0|py37h53d150a_1|py38h53d150a_1|py39h53d150a_1|py38h53d150a_0|py37h53d150a_0|py39h53d150a_0|py39hb31b9b9_1|py38hb31b9b9_1|py39h6383fca_0|py37h6383fca_0|py37hdcdd103_4|py39hdcdd103_4|py310h5f09236_0|py39h4a83355_0']

Package six conflicts for:
librosa -> six[version='>=1.3']
jsonschema -> six[version='>=1.11.0']
jsonschema -> pyrsistent[version='>=0.14.0,!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2'] -> six
pickleshare -> pathlib2 -> six[version='>=1.13.0']
librosa -> packaging[version='>=20.0'] -> six
pandas -> python-dateutil[version='>=2.8.1'] -> six[version='>=1.5']
tensorflow -> tensorboard[version='>=2.5.0'] -> six[version='>=1.10.0|>=1.15.0|>=1.12.0']
seaborn -> patsy -> six

Package scikit-learn conflicts for:
librosa -> scikit-learn[version='>=0.14.0,!=0.19.0|>=0.19.1']
scikit-learn
kneed -> scikit-learn

Package certifi conflicts for:
seaborn -> matplotlib-base[version='>=2.1.2'] -> certifi[version='>=2020.06.20']
pandas -> setuptools[version='<60.0.0'] -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
jsonschema -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26']
librosa -> setuptools -> certifi[version='>=2016.09|>=2016.9.26|>=2020.06.20']
matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.1,<3.5.2.0a0'] -> certifi[version='>=2020.06.20']

Package setuptools conflicts for:
librosa -> resampy[version='>=0.2.0'] -> setuptools[version='>=48']
tensorflow -> tensorboard[version='>=2.5.0'] -> setuptools[version='>=41.0.0']
pandas -> setuptools[version='<60.0.0']
seaborn -> pandas[version='>=0.14.0'] -> setuptools[version='<60.0.0']
jsonschema -> setuptools
pandas -> numexpr[version='>=2.7.1'] -> setuptools
librosa -> setuptools
matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.4.3,<3.4.4.0a0'] -> setuptools
scikit-learn -> joblib[version='>=0.11'] -> setuptools

Package readline conflicts for:
jsonschema -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
librosa -> python -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
pytz -> python -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
watchdog -> python -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
kneed -> python -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
scikit-learn -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
tensorflow -> python=3.8 -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
numpy -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
rdp -> python[version='>=3.6'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
matplotlib -> python[version='>=3.9,<3.10.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
fpdf -> python[version='>=3'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
python-levenshtein -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
pickleshare -> python[version='>=3'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
seaborn -> python -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
pandas -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']
scipy -> python[version='>=3.10,<3.11.0a0'] -> readline[version='>=7.0,<8.0a0|>=8.0,<9.0a0|>=8.1,<9.0a0|>=8.1.2,<9.0a0']

Package scipy conflicts for:
librosa -> scipy[version='>=0.14.0|>=1.2.0|>=1.0.0']
seaborn -> scipy[version='>=0.15.2|>=1.0|>=1.0.1']
librosa -> resampy[version='>=0.2.0'] -> scipy[version='>=0.13|>=1.1.0|>=0.19.1|>=1.3.2']
seaborn -> statsmodels[version='>=0.5.0'] -> scipy[version='>=1.2|>=1.3']
kneed -> scipy
tensorflow -> tensorflow-base==2.5.0=eigen_py38h55c2ddf_0 -> scipy[version='>=1.6.2|>=1.7.1|>=1.7.3']
scikit-learn -> scipy[version='>=0.19.1|>=1.1.0|>=1.3.2']
scipy
kneed -> scikit-learn -> scipy[version='>=0.19.1|>=1.1.0|>=1.3.2']

Package numpy conflicts for:
kneed -> scikit-learn -> numpy[version='>=1.16.4,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.21.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.6,<2.0a0|>=1.18.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.4,<2.0a0|>=1.17.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.4,<2.0a0|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0|>=1.18.1,<2.0a0']
pandas -> bottleneck[version='>=1.3.1'] -> numpy[version='>=1.18.4,<2.0a0|>=1.21.3,<2.0a0']
librosa -> numba[version='>=0.38.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.10.0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.21.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.6,<2.0a0|>=1.19.5,<2.0a0|>=1.18.5,<2.0a0|>=1.17.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0|>=1.21.4,<2.0a0|>=1.19.4,<2.0a0|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0|>=1.16.4,<2.0a0|>=1.18.1,<2.0a0|>=1.17']
seaborn -> pandas[version='>=0.14.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.16.3,<2.0a0|>=1.16.4,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0|>=1.21.5,<2.0a0|>=1.20.1,<2.0a0|>=1.19.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.6,<2.0a0|>=1.18.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.4,<2.0a0|>=1.17.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.4,<2.0a0|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0|>=1.18.1,<2.0a0|>=1.20.3,<2.0a0|>=1.17|>=1.4.0']
librosa -> numpy[version='>=1.15.0|>=1.17.0|>=1.8.0']
scikit-learn -> scipy[version='>=1.1.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.18.1,<2.0a0']
matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.1,<3.5.2.0a0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.17|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0|>=1.21.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.4,<2.0a0|>=1.19.5,<2.0a0|>=1.18.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0|>=1.21.6,<2.0a0|>=1.17.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.4,<2.0a0']
numpy
pandas -> numpy[version='>=1.16.3,<2.0a0|>=1.16.4,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0|>=1.21.5,<2.0a0|>=1.20.1,<2.0a0|>=1.19.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.6,<2.0a0|>=1.18.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.4,<2.0a0|>=1.17.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.4,<2.0a0|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0']
scikit-learn -> numpy[version='>=1.16.4,<2.0a0|>=1.16.5,<2.0a0|>=1.16.6,<2.0a0|>=1.21.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.6,<2.0a0|>=1.18.5,<2.0a0|>=1.21.4,<2.0a0|>=1.17.5,<2.0a0|>=1.19.4,<2.0a0|>=1.19.2,<2.0a0|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0']
seaborn -> numpy[version='>=1.13.3|>=1.15|>=1.9.3']
kneed -> numpy
tensorflow -> tensorboard[version='>=2.5.0'] -> numpy[version='>=1.12.0|>=1.19|>=1.16.1|>=1.20|>=1.21.2,<2.0a0|>=1.22.3,<2.0a0']
rdp -> numpy

Package pytz conflicts for:
matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='>=2.2.5,<2.2.6.0a0'] -> pytz
pandas -> pytz[version='>=2017.2|>=2017.3|>=2020.1']
pytz
librosa -> matplotlib-base[version='>=1.5.0'] -> pytz
seaborn -> pandas[version='>=0.14.0'] -> pytz[version='>=2017.2|>=2017.3|>=2020.1']

Package libgfortran4 conflicts for:
librosa -> scipy[version='>=0.14.0'] -> libgfortran4[version='>=7.5.0']
numpy -> libopenblas[version='>=0.3.10,<1.0a0'] -> libgfortran4[version='7.5.0.*|>=7.5.0']
scipy -> libgfortran4[version='>=7.5.0']
seaborn -> scipy[version='>=0.15.2'] -> libgfortran4[version='>=7.5.0']
scipy -> libgfortran-ng -> libgfortran4=7.5.0
kneed -> scipy -> libgfortran4[version='>=7.5.0']
scikit-learn -> scipy[version='>=1.1.0'] -> libgfortran4[version='>=7.5.0']

Package matplotlib conflicts for:
seaborn -> matplotlib[version='>=1.4.3|>=2.2|>=2.1.2']
librosa -> matplotlib[version='>=1.5.0']
matplotlib

Package pypy3.6 conflicts for:
pandas -> numexpr[version='>=2.7.1'] -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.*|7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*|>=7.3.1|>=7.3.3']
pytz -> python -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*']
rdp -> numpy -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*|>=7.3.1|>=7.3.2|>=7.3.3']
watchdog -> python -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.*|7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*']
librosa -> matplotlib[version='>=1.5.0'] -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*|>=7.3.1|>=7.3.2|>=7.3.3']
scikit-learn -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.2|>=7.3.3']
numpy -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.*|7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*']
pandas -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.2']
matplotlib -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.2|>=7.3.3']
watchdog -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.1|>=7.3.2|>=7.3.3']
kneed -> numpy -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*|>=7.3.1|>=7.3.2|>=7.3.3']
scikit-learn -> scipy[version='>=1.1.0'] -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.*|7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*|>=7.3.1']
python-levenshtein -> python[version='>=3.6,<3.7.0a0'] -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.*|7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*']
fpdf -> python[version='>=3'] -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*']
jsonschema -> pyrsistent[version='>=0.14.0,!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2'] -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.*|7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*|>=7.3.1|>=7.3.2|>=7.3.3']
seaborn -> matplotlib[version='>=1.4.3'] -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*|>=7.3.1|>=7.3.2|>=7.3.3']
scipy -> numpy[version='>=1.16.6,<2.0a0'] -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.*|7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*|>=7.3.3']
pickleshare -> python[version='>=3'] -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.*|7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*|>=7.3.3']
scipy -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.1|>=7.3.2']
pickleshare -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.2']
numpy -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.1|>=7.3.2|>=7.3.3']
matplotlib -> tornado -> pypy3.6[version='7.3.*|7.3.0.*|7.3.1.*|7.3.2.*|7.3.3.*|>=7.3.1']
python-levenshtein -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.2|>=7.3.3']

Package packaging conflicts for:
matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.5.1,<3.5.2.0a0'] -> packaging[version='>=20.0']
pandas -> numexpr[version='>=2.7.1'] -> packaging
seaborn -> statsmodels[version='>=0.5.0'] -> packaging[version='>=20.0|>=21.3']
librosa -> pooch[version='>=1.0'] -> packaging
librosa -> packaging[version='>=20.0']

Package libpng conflicts for:
librosa -> matplotlib-base[version='>=1.5.0'] -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0']
seaborn -> matplotlib-base[version='>=2.1.2'] -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0']
tensorflow -> tensorflow-base==2.5.0=eigen_py38h55c2ddf_0 -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0']
matplotlib -> matplotlib-base[version='>=3.2.2,<3.2.3.0a0'] -> libpng[version='>=1.6.37,<1.7.0a0']

Package gdbm conflicts for:
numpy -> pypy3.9[version='>=7.3.9'] -> gdbm[version='>=1.18,<1.19.0a0']
watchdog -> pypy3.8[version='>=7.3.9'] -> gdbm[version='>=1.18,<1.19.0a0']
matplotlib -> pypy3.9[version='>=7.3.9'] -> gdbm[version='>=1.18,<1.19.0a0']
scipy -> pypy3.8[version='>=7.3.9'] -> gdbm[version='>=1.18,<1.19.0a0']
pickleshare -> pypy3.6[version='>=7.3.2'] -> gdbm[version='>=1.18,<1.19.0a0']
python-levenshtein -> pypy3.8[version='>=7.3.9'] -> gdbm[version='>=1.18,<1.19.0a0']
pandas -> pypy3.8[version='>=7.3.9'] -> gdbm[version='>=1.18,<1.19.0a0']
scikit-learn -> pypy3.7[version='>=7.3.7'] -> gdbm[version='>=1.18,<1.19.0a0']

Package python conflicts for:
kneed -> python
kneed -> numpy -> python[version='>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.10,<3.11.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.9,<3.10.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0',build='*_73_pypy|*_cpython|*_73_pypy|*_cpython|*_73_pypy|*_cpython']

Package pandas conflicts for:
pandas
seaborn -> pandas[version='>=0.14.0|>=0.23|>=0.22.0']
seaborn -> statsmodels[version='>=0.5.0'] -> pandas[version='>=0.21|>=1.0']

Package _openmp_mutex conflicts for:
librosa -> numba[version='>=0.38.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=5.1']
numpy -> blas=[build=openblas] -> _openmp_mutex[version='*|>=4.5|>=5.1',build=*_llvm]
scikit-learn -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5']
pandas -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5|>=5.1']
scikit-learn -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=5.1']
scipy -> blas=[build=openblas] -> _openmp_mutex[version='*|>=4.5|>=5.1',build=*_llvm]
kneed -> scikit-learn -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=5.1']
python-levenshtein -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.2.0'] -> _openmp_mutex[version='>=4.5|>=5.1']

Package _libgcc_mutex conflicts for:
python-levenshtein -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.2.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
pandas -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.2.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
scikit-learn -> _openmp_mutex -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
scipy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.2.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]
numpy -> libgcc-ng[version='>=10.2.0'] -> _libgcc_mutex[version='*|0.1',build=main]

Package liblapacke conflicts for:
numpy -> blas=[build=openblas] -> liblapacke[version='3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.9.0|3.9.0|3.9.0',build='2_openblas|3_openblas|6_openblas|8_openblas|9_openblas|10_openblas|11_openblas|14_openblas|16_openblas|6_openblas|7_openblas|8_openblas|10_openblas|12_linuxaarch64_openblas|13_linuxaarch64_openblas|15_linuxaarch64_openblas|16_linuxaarch64_openblas|14_linuxaarch64_openblas|11_linuxaarch64_openblas|9_openblas|5_openblas|17_openblas|15_openblas|12_openblas|7_openblas|5_openblas|4_openblas']
scipy -> blas=[build=openblas] -> liblapacke[version='3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.8.0|3.9.0|3.9.0|3.9.0',build='2_openblas|3_openblas|6_openblas|8_openblas|9_openblas|10_openblas|11_openblas|14_openblas|16_openblas|6_openblas|7_openblas|8_openblas|10_openblas|12_linuxaarch64_openblas|13_linuxaarch64_openblas|15_linuxaarch64_openblas|16_linuxaarch64_openblas|14_linuxaarch64_openblas|11_linuxaarch64_openblas|9_openblas|5_openblas|17_openblas|15_openblas|12_openblas|7_openblas|5_openblas|4_openblas']

Package typing_extensions conflicts for:
jsonschema -> importlib-metadata -> typing_extensions[version='>=3.6.4']
tensorflow -> tensorflow-base==2.5.0=eigen_py38h55c2ddf_0 -> typing_extensions[version='>=3.6.6|>=3.7.4']
jsonschema -> typing_extensions

Package requests conflicts for:
tensorflow -> tensorboard[version='>=2.5.0'] -> requests[version='>=2.21.0,<3']
librosa -> pooch[version='>=1.0'] -> requests[version='>=2.19.0']
```